# Safest way to save binary file with numpy to be read

Tags: android, python, arrays, numpy, binary

I need to save some arrays using numpy, to be later read with an Android Java APP and another python application using numpy. So far, I've been using numpy.ndarray.tofile and numpy.ndarray.fromfile for io, both of which I like very much due to the simplicity of both. My sollution for writing and reading such binary arrays were:

```
def write_feature_bin_file(filepath, features_list):

if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    os.remove(filepath)

allfeatures = numpy.vstack(features_list)
header = [allfeatures.shape[0]]
try:
    header.append(allfeatures.shape[1])
except Exception as e:
    header.append(1)

if allfeatures.dtype.name == 'uint8':
    header.append(0)
else:
    header.append(5)

header = numpy.array(header, dtype=numpy.int32)

try:
    binf = open(filepath, 'a')
    header.tofile(binf)
    allfeatures.tofile(binf)
    binf.close()
except Exception as e:
    print "Unable to save file: ", filepath
    print e

return
```

and

```
def read_feature_bin_file(filepath):

try:
    binf = open(filepath, 'r')

    header = numpy.fromfile(f, count=3, dtype=numpy.int32)
    print header

    rows = header[0]
    cols = header[1]
    dt = header[2]


    if dt == 0:
        features = numpy.fromfile(f, dtype=numpy.uint8)
    else:
        features = numpy.fromfile(f, dtype=numpy.float32)

    features.resize(rows, cols)
    binf.close()

    return features

except Exception as e:

    print "Unable to read file: ", filepath
    print e
    return None
```

What I'm doing here is simply writing a small header to the output file, containing three integers describing number of rows, number of cols and type of the data, which can be either uint8 or float32, and then appending the rest of my data to the file. When reading, I read the first three elements of the header to check the array properties, and then read the remaining of the file accordingly. The problem is: I don't know if this is safe, especially regarding the endianness of the system that is going to read this file.

What would be the best way for me to ensure that this file can be correctly read in any system? I know that numpy has the "save" and "load" functions, both those save in a .npz or .npy format, but I don't know how to port them to be read in my Android App.

Comment: Well give it a try. You will quickly find out if your Android app can read it correctly. And what is numpy?

Comment: Pickle format should be portable.  The docs on it are at https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html and https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [two main options.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_files_and_byte_swap)

**1. Always save with the same endianness**

You can strictly define the endianness as part of the file format specification and program file readers and writers accordingly. 
For example with Numpy you can specify the endianness as part of the [dtype character code](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html): `<f4` represents a little-endian 4-byte floating point number (=float32) and `>f4` a big-endian. In order to always write in little-endian format, the writing routine could contain something like this:

```
if allfeatures.dtype.name == 'uint8':
    header.append(0)
else:
    allfeatures = allfeatures.astype('<f4', copy=False)
    header.append(5)

header = numpy.array(header, dtype='<i4')
```

**2. Specify the endianness in the header of the file**

This is what the Numpy `.npy` format implements under the covers (it stores the dtype character code returned by `ndarray.dtype.descr`). The `.npy` format is super easy to use from Numpy, but probably not so much from the Java application. So maybe the easiest but still solid solution is to store an additional flag in front of the header. That way the endianness can be easily determined before the array dimensions are read from the header.

Alternatively, it would also make sense to determine endianness from the third flag in your current header, but then you'd have to change the identifier for `uint8` (zero has the same representation in both big- as little-endianness, so can't be used). It could be programmed like so:

```
def read_feature_bin_file(filepath):

    with open(filepath, 'rb') as binf:
        header = numpy.fromfile(binf, count=3, dtype='<i4')
        if header[2] not in [1, 5]:  # Check endianness
            header = header.view('>i4')

        rows, cols, dt = header
        dtype = 'u1' if dt==1 else header.dtype.byteorder + 'f4'
        features = numpy.fromfile(binf, dtype)

    features.shape = (rows, cols)
    return features
```

Comment: Thank you! I specifically like encoding this on the formatting flag of the header, very clever solution.